# Checkear si una variable es undefined en Angular

Tags: html, angular, undefined

Traigo una petición de un servidor, el cual trae información. Alguna de estas variables, según la petición que hago, vienen como "undefined".

Necesito mostrar en html un formulario u/o otro según el valor de estas variables.

Estoy intentando esto a raiz de que null==undefined [Sacado de aquí la conclusión](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647867/how-to-determine-if-variable-is-undefined-or-null)

```
*ngIf="variable != null"
*ngIf="variable" //TAMPOCO FUNCIONA
```

Pero parece no funcionar, ya que siempre me muestra el formulario.

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás malinterpretando algunas cosas. Si bien la respuesta que aparece en S.O. dice textualmente:

> Because null == undefined is true

Realmente no se refiere a que sean iguales y puedas compararlas alegremente, de hecho te sugiero que en lo posible **no** hagas ese tipo de comparaciones. ([Comparación de conversión de tipos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Comparison_Operators))

Para solucionar tu problema tienes algunas opciones:

1. Usar simplemente el operador `!` ante puesto a tu variable. En este caso te interesa ponerlo 2 veces. Más adelante explico el porqué. Sin embargo esto tiene un problema, ya que si la variable que recibes es numérica, y el cero (0) es un valor válido para mostrar el elemento, esta técnica no te servirá.
2. Usar la comparación estricta. Esto tal vez sea lo más adecuado, ya que de esta forma te aseguras que sólo mostrarás el elemento si la variable es diferente de `undefined` en todo sentido.

Dicho esto, tienes estas dos formas de realizar la tarea:

```
// usando doble negación
<div id="elemento" *ngif="!!variable">

// usando comparación estricta
<div id="elemento2" *ngif="variable !== undefined">
```

En el primer caso se realiza una doble negación, que realiza una conversión de la variable a un tipo `boolean`, cuyo valor será `true` si la variable es [`truthy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Truthy) (valor verdadero), y será `false` si la misma es [`falsy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Falsy)(valor no verdadero).

En el segundo caso, estamos realizando una comparación estricta. Dicha comparación (`!==`) devolverá `false` únicamente si la variable es de tipo `undefined`, cualquier otro tipo distinto que tenga la variable, devolverá `true`. Así, el elemento sólo se mostrará si la variable recibida es distinta de `undefined`.

Espero que esto responda tu duda.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Aunque para mi caso me sirve con el primero, voy a usar el segundo bajo tu recomendación. Es la primera vez des de que programo que uso la doble negación !! Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

La opción más corta seria usar un metodo para el ngIf
Prueba esto *ngIf="variableNula()" en la vista
y luego del lado del controlador armas el metodo

variableNula(){

if ( variable == null || variable == undefined || variable == "null" || variable == "undefined") { return false } else { return true }

}

Este metodo se fija de distintas formas si la variable es nula, si es nula retorna un false al ngIf, si esto ocurre no se mostrará la variable, pero si la variable trae algo que no sea null o undefined, va a retornar un true al ngIf, esto hará que se muestre la variable en la vista.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Este camino era el que iba a intentar implementar por desesperación. Gracias por el aporte.